# How to change the radius in drawcircle() by edittext?

Tags: android

I want to get a value from edittext and pass it to radius, here is my code

```
class GetRadius extends Activity {
private float radius = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(activity_main);

    final EditText editText= findViewById(R.id.myText);
    Button button=findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            radius=Float.valueOf(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}
public float MyRadius() {
    return radius;
}
}
```

and I try to get radius in below class, its a part of a public class

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    GetRadius getRadius=new GetRadius();
    float radius=getRadius.MyRadius();

    for(Coordinate pt:points){
        paint.setColor(pt.colour);
        canvas.drawCircle(pt.x,pt.y,radius,paint);
    }
}
```

It shows no bug, but just can't draw the point on view. and if I change radius to a number like 20,12... it will works. I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: show full code have onDraw method?

Comment: Did you check the value of `radius`?